# How to map through a list and return it's data in widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

( I know this type of question have been asked before but I could not understand the solution)

Hi guy's, I am still learning flutter. I want to display cards with movie names and their prices.
This is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(leading: Text("${Movie.name}"),trailing: Text($"Movie.price"),),
    );
  }
}



class Movie {
 
  String? name;
  int? price;

 Movie({this.name,this.price});

}

 List cinemas = [
    Movie(name:"kingkong",price:25),
    Movie(name:"hanuman",price:25),
    Movie(name:"king polo",price:25),
    Movie(name:"ashiqyue",price:25),
    Movie(name:"hero",price:25),
    Movie(name:"zero",price:25),
    Movie(name:"kilo",price:25),
];
```

Comment: simple return ListView(children: cinemas.map((movie) => Card(
      child: ListTile(leading: Text("${movie.name}"),trailing: Text($"movie.price"),),
    )));

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using **ListView.builder** like below :

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: cinemas.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Text("${cinemas[index].name}"),
                  trailing: Text("${cinemas[index].price}"),
                ),
              ))
```

Also making `List cinemas` to `List<Movie> cinemas` is good practice as you are creating a list of particular object

Comment: thank you so much @Diwyansh, I'm struggling to create such logic for data. can you plz tell me where to learn and get clarity

Comment: I think to learn that you can go through the tutorials that are available on Flutter's official website or follow articles available on Medium. Also mark this as answered if it worked for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This code if you have List with **fixed number of items in your List** and you can use **ListView.builder** when number of items in List is not Fixed(when fetching List from API)

```
Column(
        children: List.generate(cinemas.length, (index) => Card(
    child: ListTile(
    leading: Text("${cinemas[index].name}"),
    trailing: Text("${cinemas[index].price}"),
    ),
    ),
      ),
     
    )
```